# Byte to megabyte conversion doesn't work

Tags: java, android, megabyte

i need convert the byte in Megabyte in my application but something is wrong.. First of all, i need display for example 1.2MB and not 1MB.. now, i have this declaration:

```
public long mStartRX = 0;
```

then in the onCreate

```
mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
```

finally this to find the data usage in byte:

```
final long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes) + " " + "Bytes");
```

**i tryied this solution:**

```
final long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()/(1024*1024)- mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes) + " " + "Bytes");
```

but the result is not correct.. Infact i display something like: `-1258912654` and of course it's not correct.  How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Uhm, maybe like `(TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX) / (1024*1024)` ?

Comment: I was thinking the same solution but it display 0.0MB forever :(

Comment: you are dividing 2 value and result is float not long.

Comment: It displays 0MB because mStartRX and rxBytes are equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes some math skills here I think, and also knowledge of integer/floatingpoint division. But this code should work

```
long mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
...
long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;

RX.setText(rxBytes + " Bytes");
RX.setText(String.format("%.2f MB",rxBytes /(1024f*1024f)));
```

The String.format is used to get exactly 2 decimals (%.2f) from a floating point varible/expression. Also "1024f" means 1024 in float, because we want floating point division, not integer division.

**Edit**

To save it in variable

```
float rxMBytes = rxBytes/(1024f*1024f);
RX.setText(String.format("%.2f MB",rxMBytes ));
```

Comment: Could be possible recevie 255,85 MB? I'm display the total MB (3g+wifi)

Comment: and is it possible save in a variable the value in mb? like `RXMB = (String.format("%.2f MB",rxBytes /(1024f*1024f)));` or something like that.

Comment: Impossible to say ´cause I have no clue what you are measuring (in place of the dots).

Comment: because i need insert this value in a setValue position like here: `d2.setValue(txBytes);`